# How to sort aggregations by top hits field (text field)? Or is there any possibility to sort aggregations by text field (without using _term)

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch

As in title, I have a problem with sorting Elasticsearch aggregation by text field. Is there any possibility to do it? Using top hits or something like this? Now i'm using term aggregation and i can sort by aggregation field using _term, but i need to sort this aggregations by different field. I know how to do it with fields with numeric value. For instance using max, min, sum etc.

It will be great if i can do it like this (but i cant):

```
    "aggs": {
        "Variants": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "variant",
                "order": {
                    "top_Song_hits": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_Song_hits": {
                    "sum": {
                        "name": {
                            "order": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "Variants": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "variant",
                "order": {
                    "name_agg": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "name_agg": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "Variants": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "variant",
                "order": {
                    "details": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "details": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "_source": {
                            "include": ["name"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In last case i get error:

```
"reason": "Invalid aggregation order path [details]. Buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
```

Comment: Why doesn't your example work? It seems to match [the examples in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order). "I can't" is not at all helpful. Aside: `_term` is deprecated; use `_key` now.

Comment: "...Now i'm using term aggregation and i can sort by aggregation field using _term, but i need to sort this aggregations by different field..." I dont want to sort by _key. For instance i want to sort by name

Comment: Where name is a document field? That doesn't make sense. terms is a bucket aggregation. Each bucket contains many documents, so there is no single name to sort by.

Comment: Ok, i know it doesn't make sense, but i need to achieve something like this. Maybe i need to use something different then terms, but i dont know what.

Comment: In my case i have list of products and i need to group them by variant_id and sort it by products name.

Comment: If you want to sort them by name you have to have a bucket for each individual name. I.e. put a terms aggregation for the name field at or near the top of your aggregation tree.

Comment: Ok, i can do it, but how can i later group my products by variant_id?

Answer (score 1):

i found solution for my problem here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html

Comment: hi @sqlldev would be great if you could post your solution code here as well

Comment: I solved my problem using `collapse`.
I added to request something like this to collapse response data by `some_field` you can use it like DISTINCT in mysql.

`['collapse' => ['field' => 'some_field']];`